# grok pattern for extracting a portion of URI

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, grok

I've been tasked with managing our ELK stack and writing rules for elastalert, but need a specific part of one field I already have as its own field in order to use elastalert's query_key functionality on that field. We're using these rules here:

https://github.com/hpcugent/logstash-patterns/blob/master/files/grok-patterns

- and the field I need is one part of a URIPATHPARAM which we already catch:

/path_field_1/UID/path_field_2/path_params

Where UID is a 32 character unique identifier of 0-9,a-z,A-Z. I can access the whole URI in Kibana, but I eventually need UID to be its own field so that I can use elastalert's query_key over it. The lines containing this UID are always preceded by "/path_to_field_1/".

As a total novice, I'm not sure what might be some (good?) ways to achieve this - and the documentation (which I've been pouring over for a week) is pretty arcane.

Comment: https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/tree/master/patterns is their official pattern repo

Comment: these docs, arcane? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track looking at grok, if the preceding bit is always the same, you could use grok to grab the UID

```
grok {
  match => {
    "uri_field" => "/path_to_field_1/%{DATA:UID}/%{GREEDYDATA}"
  }
}
```

Comment: They are a bit short on examples, luckily SO is here!

Comment: Wonderful - this is actually what I was initially thinking was the solution, but it's very difficult to discern that that is how it works from the docs. Thanks! 

uri_field corresponds to the URI field I have already captured, and this will produce a field that is solely the UID, named UID, correct?

Comment: it should, the `%{GREEDYDATA}` is not stored because it is an unnamed capture which grok, by default, discards